# Why does the nm tool output for the extern-only and defined-only options overlap?

Tags: ios, mach-o, nm

I'll start by giving my understanding of the options:

1. extern-only: Show me only those symbols which are referenced by the binary but whose definitions (the code or variable) will be provided by another binary
2. defined-only: Show me only those symbols whose definitions are contained in the binary.

Here are my commands and their output:

```
$nm -defined-only GenerationOfNow | grep FIRAZeroingWeakContainer  
000000010002c128 t -[FIRAZeroingWeakContainer .cxx_destruct]  
000000010002c0fb t -[FIRAZeroingWeakContainer object]  
000000010002c114 t -[FIRAZeroingWeakContainer setObject:]  
000000010021a218 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAZeroingWeakContainer  
00000001002177f8 s _OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRAZeroingWeakContainer._object  
000000010021a1f0 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FIRAZeroingWeakContainer

$nm -extern-only GenerationOfNow | grep FIRAZeroingWeakContainer  
000000010021a218 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAZeroingWeakContainer  
000000010021a1f0 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FIRAZeroingWeakContainer
```

As you can see, the -extern-only output is a subset of the -defined-only output. Why? Perhaps my question should be: What is the meaning of those items which have a S in the second column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing `-extern-only` with `-undefined-only`.

There are two concepts that are being mixed here:

- extern vs. local (in C `extern` vs. `static`, "local" is sometimes also called "private")
- defined vs. undefined

The former describes the *availability* of a symbol while the latter describes its *origin*. And yes, even the notion of a private undefined symbol exists, as per `man nm`:

> Each symbol name is preceded by its value (blanks if undefined). [...] A lower case u in a dynamic shared library indicates a undefined reference to a private external in another module in the same library.

Now, when using `-undefined-only` you actually do get the complement of `-undefined-only`

```
bash$ nm test.dylib 
0000000000000f60 T _derp
0000000000000f70 t _herp
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

```
bash$ nm -defined-only test.dylib 
0000000000000f60 T _derp
0000000000000f70 t _herp
```

```
bash$ nm -undefined-only test.dylib 
_printf
dyld_stub_binder
```

```
bash$ nm -extern-only test.dylib 
0000000000000f60 T _derp
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

`-extern-only` does not seem to have a complementary flag however.